# mongodb stores large size documents and query is very slow

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I store a very long string to my document in mongodb server, my document looks like

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5280efdbe4b062c93b582118"),
    "viewID": 1,
    "content": "a very long string"
}
```

and there are about hundreds of such documents in the same collection. I have indexed the collection.

The problem is that I just execute a very simple query

```
db.blog.find({viewID:1});
```

and then get a very long time (over several hours) to wait for the response, and no any error message displayed, server status is OK. But I just add `db.blog.find({viewID:1}).limit(1);` mongodb returns the result at once.

How can I do to solve the problem or improve the performance??

Here is my explain:

```
db.blog.find({viewID:1}).explain();
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor viewID_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 377,
    "nscannedObjects" : 377,
    "nscanned" : 377,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 377,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 377,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 45,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "viewID" : [
            [
                1,
                1
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "Server:27017"
}
```

Here is colStat:

```
db.blog.stats();
{
    "ns" : "***.blog",
    "count" : 98582,
    "size" : 2330759632,
    "avgObjSize" : 23642.851960804204,
    "storageSize" : 2958364672,
    "numExtents" : 18,
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "lastExtentSize" : 778276864,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 6540800,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 4055296,
        "viewID_1" : 2485504
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: how many documents do you have and how big is the document?

Comment: Please tell us **how** you indexed the collection. Also, please run your query with `.explain()` added to the end of your command and post the output. It tells us if and how your index is used.

Comment: I'm going to guess that viewID is not indexed?

Comment: Let's get things straight. If you run `db.blog.find({viewID:1});` from shell it takes several hours but if you run `db.blog.find({viewID:1}).explain();` it gives you `"millis" : 45`?

Comment: Yes @zero323, but the same situation happens at localhost.

Comment: Could you define very long string?

Comment: @AlanSpencer, it's about thousands of chinese words per documents, and there are hundreds of documents per viewID.

Comment: What happens when you don't pull back the text - i.e. db.blog.find({viewID:1},{viewID:1})

Comment: @AlanSpencer There is no any response displayed in the terminal after I enter the query command. I wait for a day long, but it still does not have any response after all.

Comment: This is for the field selection find? find({viewID:1}).limit(1) returns immediately? find({viewID:1}) never returns? have you tried find({viewID:1}).limit(2) etc?

Comment: It got no response when executing `find({viewID:1}).limit(x), x>10. I've checked the mongodb log, the server did receive the query request, but no any advanced operation is performed. The mongod service also did not appear at the top3 cpu comsumed processes. I check the network throughput, it's not found high transmission rate, too. I got stuck at last.

Comment: I execute `find({viewID:1}).limit(1)` and the server returns immediately.